# Processing OS Highways data into a network dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, routing, ordnance-survey

I am looking for advice in how to process highways data into a network dataset in ArcGIS for use in the Network Analyst extension

My company has a partners contract so i have access to the data, but I do not know how to process from the GZ format into shp files? I also have a Network Analyst extension.

We have limited access to other tools so looking for a free method!

Comment: Can you be more explicit in your question body as to whether you have access to ArcGIS Network Analyst, or not, please?

Comment: Have a look on esri code sharing website there is a UK data loader toolbox created by esri UK.

Comment: A gz file is just an archive (like zip). Have you checked the contents? What is inside? Maybe it's Shapefiles already?! If not I believe the OS provides data as Shapefiles as well as GML, if you look in the right place. Otherwise, I know of software to convert OS GML to Shape, but it wouldn't be free.

Answer (score 1):

It [ships as GML 3.2.1](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/os-mastermap-highways-network.html) so [`ogr2ogr`](https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) will convert it for you. Hint, you probably don't want it as shapefiles as there is a whole bunch of stuff you need to fix before it is a routing network (like the nodes where bridges go over motorways). I would load it into a PostGIS database and mess with it there. Again, `ogr2ogr` is a good tool for that or you could use [Astun's Loader](https://github.com/AstunTechnology/Loader) (also open source).

**Disclosure** I work for Astun (but not on loader). If you get stuck we can sell you a [support package](https://astuntechnology.com/services/#open-source-support) on this stuff.